# Mediation analysis with a tobit regression is failing to find the outcome variable

Tags: r, regression

I am trying to run a mediation analysis with the `mediation` package in R. My outcome variable needs to be modeled with a tobit model (censored data).

When I try to run it, it claims that the outcome variable cannot be found, although it is in the dataframe.
See reproducable example:

```
library(mediation)
test <- data.frame(mediator = c(0.333,0.201,0.343,0.133,0.240),
                   DV = c(0.152,2.318,0.899,0.327,1.117),
                   outcome=c(1.715,1.716,0.544,3.284,3.599))
mediator_model <- lm(mediator ~ DV, data = test)
outcome_model <- vglm(outcome ~ mediator + DV,
                      tobit(Upper = 4, Lower = -4), link = "identity",data = test)

med <- mediate(mediator_model, outcome_model, treat = "DV", mediator = "mediator")
```

When I run this, I get the error
`Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'outcome' not found`,
even though the outcome model runs without a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem lies in `mediation::mediate`:

> a fitted model object for mediator/outcome. Can be of class 'lm', 'polr','bayespolr', 'glm', 'bayesglm', 'gam', 'rq', 'survreg', or 'merMod'.

Try `AER::tobit` for your outcome_model, instead of `vglm`. Hopefully the `mediate` will work.

Comment: That did work, thank you.
In case anyone else comes across this, I did need to change the syntax a little, this is what worked for my model above (note that `AER::tobit` needs to receive the data as a list):
`AER::tobit(outcome ~ mediator + DV, left = -4, right = 4, data = as.list(test))`